# jQuery append object and add string

Tags: jquery, append

Trying to get div 1 into div 2 and wrap brackets around the text.

Attempt

```
$('.div1').append('(' + $('.div2') + ')');
```

Before

```
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="2">blah</div>
```

What I want

```
<div class="1"><div class="2">(blah)</div></div>
```

Comment: You're referencing elements that have the classes `div1` and `div2` but your example is using elements with the class `1` and `2`.

Comment: @Matt Coady you have 9 answers. None of them worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.div1').append($('.div2').html('(' + $('.div2').html() + ')'));
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7R3G8/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your selectors: `.div1` and `.div2`, these are searching for elements that have the class of `div1` and `div2`; whereas you want the `div` *elements*, with class `1` or `2`.

Therefore I'd suggest:

```
$('div.2').text(function(i,t){
    return '(' + t + ')';
});
$('div.1').append($('div.2'));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s2pU9/1/).

Although do be aware that using a numeral character as the first character of a `class`, or `id`, can be problematic in CSS.

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $('div.2').text('('+$('div.2').text()+')');
    $('div.1').html($('div.2'));
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5dU7r/1)**

Answer (score 0):

You should clone the element then add the parentesis to it, and append it to the other div. After that you can always remove the old element.

**JS**

```
var div2 = $('.div2').clone();
div2.text('(' + div2.text() + ')');
$('.div1').append(div2);
```

**Html**

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2">blah</div>
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zZ45C/3/)

Comment: This will give a result like this, `<div class="1">(<div class="2">blah</div>)</div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    //$('.div1').append('(', $('.div2'), ')'); //this is better way but you can try following
    $('.div1').append($('.div2'));
    $('.div2').html('('+$('.div2').html()+')');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/jNU4B/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var html = $('.div2');
var text = $('.div2').text();
$(html).text("("+text+")");             
$('.div1').append(html);
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/UDf42/)

**Note:**

Name of class never starts with numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

You JS could look like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.1').append('(' + $('.2').html() + ')');
   $('.2').remove();
});
```

Here's a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/cVD6X/

Hopefully this is what you intended.

Regards,
Eric Robinson

Comment: I know i put the Div tag within the `(` and `)` but hopefully that shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps..

```
$('div.1').append($('div.2'));
$('div.2').html("(" + $('div.2').html() + ")");
```